# SwiftUI - Core Data delete item from button

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

**UPDATED:**
I was able to get this working, not 100% on the code but it's working now. If anyone has any tips to improve the code, would really appreciate it. I'm now able to delete the core data item from my main `List` using a simple `.swipeAction`.

[image]

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.date, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            
            // Main View
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(Array((1..<6).enumerated()), id: \.offset) { value in
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(value.element)")
                            Spacer()
                            if items.contains(where: {Int($0.number) == value.element} ) {
                                Text(Image(systemName: "heart.fill"))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                            }
                        }
                        .swipeActions {
                            Button(items.contains(where: {Int($0.number) == value.element}) ? "Unfavorite" : "Favorite") {
                                if items.contains(where: {Int($0.number) == value.element}) {
                                    for (index, element) in items.enumerated() {
                                        if Int(element.number) == value.element {
                                            unfavorite(items[index])
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    favorite(Float(value.element))
                                }
                                
                            }
                            .tint(items.contains(where: {Int($0.number) == value.element}) ? Color.red : Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Numbers")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "number")
                Text("Numbers")
            }
            
            
            // Saved View is working fine
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        HStack {
                            Text(String(format: "%.0f", item.number))
                            Spacer()
                            Text(Image(systemName: "heart.fill"))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        for index in indexSet {
                            viewContext.delete(items[index])
                        }
                        try? viewContext.save()
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Favorites")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                Text("Favorites")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func favorite(_ number: Float) {
        let fetchrequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        fetchrequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "number = %f", Float(number))
        do {
            let items = try viewContext.fetch(fetchrequest)
            if !items.isEmpty {
                return
            } else {
                let item = Item(context: viewContext)
                item.number = number
                item.date = Date()
                try? viewContext.save()
            }
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
    
    func unfavorite(_ item: Item) {
        viewContext.delete(item)
        try? viewContext.save()
    }
}
```

<strike>I'm adding `.swipeAction` to an item in a `List` which contains a `Button`, the button action adds items to another `List` in my Favorites `View` using Core Data. It's working fine, but I'm unsure how to unfavourite and delete the Core Data item from my Numbers `View` which would be my main view.</strike>

I can delete the saved items in my second `View`, just confused on how to delete from the main view. The `Button` would instead say delete and the color would be red if item has already been favourited.

Comment: Do you want to delete  unfavorite or them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete Core Data SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432307/how-to-delete-core-data-swiftui)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t. I’m looking to know if the item has been favourited so I can unfavourite in the main List. I can already delete the item from where it saves the favourited items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by enumerating the core data items and was able to remove the item from my main `List`. Full code is above the in the updated question.

```swift
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.date, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>


// This is the solution I found
for (index, element) in items.enumerated() {
    if Int(element.number) == value.element {
        unfavorite(items[index])
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown all of your code, so it is a bit difficult to answer, but I am presuming that your "Main List" is keeping track of the list of "favorites" items separately which is the real root of your problem. When you are using CoreData like this to show lists that are favorited, the two best ways to handle it are:

1.Using a predicate to limit the results from your fetch request:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "favorite == true")
```

This is best used when you want to show JUST the list of "favorite" items. This would essentially be static in that you can't switch back and forth between everything AND favorites (though with the proper implementation it would add items that were favorited).

2.Filter the FetchedResults using filter:

```
items.filter( {$0.favorite} ) // I could have put == true, but favorite is already a bool, so it evaluates with the ==
```

This is the more common approach as the user has access to the entire list, but can reduce it to just the favorites with the push of a button. The simple way is to use another bool to switch between the filtered and unfiltered data.

Comment: I’ve already done this. That’s not what I’m looking for. I have a list of numbers, I want to favourite a number. It then stores the value into core data. That data is put into a secondary List in a different view. I still want to know which items I have favorited in the List of numbers.

Comment: But you are storing the fact that the number stored by the particular managed object ALSO contains the information that it is a favorite is your solution. If you use `@FetchRequest` in your views, as soon as you delete the managed object and save your context, the views will refresh to reflect the change. Therefore, deleting the managed object in one view will delete it in all views if done properly. This will then cause the views to update. " I still want to know which items I have favorited in the List of numbers.": If you have deleted the item, it is no longer favorited, either.

Comment: I managed to accomplish what I was looking for without much to go on.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer for others.