# Deleting CoreData without onDelete in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

my app shows CoreData as following in VStack. List isn't possible due to ScrollView.

```
 VStack (spacing: 20) {
    ForEach(groups) { group in
        NavigationLink(destination: GroupView()) {
            ZStack (alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            
            Image(uiImage: (UIImage(data: group.groupThumbnail ?? self.image) ?? UIImage(named: "defaultGroupThumbnail"))!)
                .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets())
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(22)
            
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                
                Text("\(group.groupTitle ?? "Untitled")")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                
                Text("Consists of 5 Flowers")
            }
            .padding([.leading, .bottom], 18.0)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
        }
```

However, I can delete my entries with onDelete. Therefore, I am trying to find an alternative with .contextMenu.

```
.contextMenu {
    Button (role: .destructive) {
        withAnimation {
            self.deleteGroups(at: IndexSet.init(arrayLiteral: 0)) // This is the code I copied from the video.
        }
    } label: {
        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
    }
    Button {
        print()
    } label: {
        Label("Edit", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
    }

}
```

I saw a video in which somebody was able to delete his entry with the combination of these to codes
When tapping on "Delete", the entry should be deleted by this code:

```
func deleteGroups(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for offset in offsets {
            let group = groups[offset]
            viewContext.delete(group)
        }
        //try? viewContext.save()
    }
```

But, whenever I click this "Delete" Button in context menu, the wrong one gets deleted. I can't get the code to delete the selected entry. If anyone can help me, that would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Not that important but, is there a delete feature compared to "onDelete" (such as swiping to delete) I can still implement? And are there any possibilities for animation in my case?

Kind Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete Core Data SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432307/how-to-delete-core-data-swiftui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete it in the normal way:

```
Button (role: .destructive) {
    withAnimation {
        viewContext.delete(group)
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // show error
        }
    }
} label: {
    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
}
```

FYI I also edited your question to fix your `ForEach` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
ForEach(groups, id: \.self) { group in
```

---

```
.contextMenu {
Button (role: .destructive) {
   
        for index in groups.indices{
           if group == groups[index]{
           withAnimation{
           viewContext.delete(group)
          }
        }
      }
} label: {
    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
}
Button {
    print()
} label: {
    Label("Edit", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
}

}
```